# Can a contract trigger events in the outside world?

Tags: smart-contract, event

Is it possible for a contract to somehow trigger an event which an external process may listen for? Or is polling the only practical way currently to determine an outcome in a contract?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for smart contract to send any signal to external process however there's some alternative approach that's create processes listen to the blockchain state or event by a period of time.

One more thing, normally a smart contract is called from external tool/agent.

Comment: As the alternative method, do you mean to be saying *polling* of blockchain state by an external process?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [demux](https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js) library for listening to EOS blockchain events. As far as I know there is no event logs like in Ethereum so you have to poll the api node

- https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js